# Redirect to error page when entering invalid URL, such as example.com/ /

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-errors

My problem is that when users enter a url like:

```
example.com/ /
```

(having space between two slashes)

It will display an error:

> The configSource file 'appSettings.config' is also used in a parent,
>   this is not allowed

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config"/>
```

And it is not redirected to the custom error page (of course `customErrors mode="On"`). It shows:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error
>   Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.  Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Please help me know how to fix it.

Comment: Redirect your custom errors to a static HTML page, the details are in the exception.... An exception occured, and then when trying to serve the error page another exception occured...

Comment: Why do you need to fix this? You have a bunch of users who go `yoursite.com/ / `?

Comment: I just wonder if there is anyway to fix this. For example, no one go to example.com/wtf, but we also need to provide a 404 page.
@AydinAdn: I've created a static html as error page but it still not work. 
Thanks all!